# Выйти на других устройства при логине Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, сессия, авторизация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы после логина в админку Wordpress параллельно происходил выход на других устройствах.

В админ-панели в разделе юзер в карточке профиля есть кнопка "выйти на других устройствах". Но как сделать это автоматизировано при любом логине?